# Why does using volatile produce a different result?

Tags: c#

```
    private const int Total = 500000;
    private static volatile int _count = 0;

    private static void Main()
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Decrement);
        for (int i = 0; i < Total; i++)
        {
            _count++;
        }

        task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(_count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Decrement()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Total; i++)
        {
            _count--;
        }
    }
```

Sometimes the result is 0,sometimes the result is -xxxxxx. I don't know why. Can anybody explain it and tell me the correct usage.

Comment: @Joshua Enfield Thanks... My english is not good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`volatile` guarantees no reordering of operations and disable caching optimizations, but does not guarantees thread safety - so you can get any result from 0 to `-Total` (if every pair of `--` and `++` are properly mixed). I've covered "preper mixing" in answer to [Why the following C# multi-threaded code does not output zero though it does in debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412673/why-the-following-c-sharp-multi-threaded-code-does-not-output-zero-though-it-doe/5412742#5412742).

`volatile` is useful when you expect someone else to modify value so your code always reads reasonably recent value, which also will be consistent (i.e. for ++ you'll not get `int` consisting of high part of 0xffff and low part of (0xffff+1) - you'll get either one or another) since volatile is only applicable to types that are writen atomically.

If you want to modify counter in 2 threads - use `Interlocked.Increment`/`Interlocked.Decrement`.

Comment: i see,volatile ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.but the thread is not execute randomly,so sometimes i get 0,sometimes i get -xxxxx.I confuse by the up-to-date just now.Am i right?

Comment: @Scarface, turned out I've already wrote similar answer - check the edit.

Answer (score 3):

`volatile` does not guarantee thread-safety as it was stated in Alexei Levenkov's answer. You can use [`System.Threading.Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Interlocked.aspx).

Your example will look like something like this after that:

```
    private const int Total = 500000;
    private static volatile int _count = 0;

    private static void Main()
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Decrement);
        for (int i = 0; i < Total; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        }

        task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(_count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Decrement()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Total; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. Yes, interlocked is the way to go for changing from several places at the same time.